# Changing bootstrap navbar scroll effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am making my bootstrap navbar on scroll to change the background color to red with jquery and it do not work any help please.

HTML CODE

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:Transparent; border-color:#e74c3c;">
      <div class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;">Podlle</div>
      <div class="nabar-item">
         <a style="color:white;" href="#"<div class="navbar-text">Sign Up</div></a>
         <a style="color:white;" href="#"<div class="navbar-text">Log In</div></a>
      </div>
```

Jquery Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js">
$(document).scroll(function(){
  $(".navbar").css("background-color" , "red");  
})
```

Please Help , Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `$(document).on('scroll', function() {...` ?

Comment: Can you give me the code of on scroll please. NB: I am using jquerry

Comment: It's the same you have there. I'm just replacing `$(document).scroll` with the code I showed in my comment. Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the document to exist (DOM Ready) and then do whatever with it. With jQuery, you can do that using the shortcut `$(callbackFuncion)`.

The following is an example code I've wrote that will print to the console when the page scrolls and update the element with class `nav-bar` to have a red background:

```
$(function () { // This will wait for DOMReady
  $(document).on('scroll', function () {
    console.log("Scrolling.");
    $('.nav-bar').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});
```

This is a full sample code working: http://jsfiddle.net/xa8doyb4/

Comment: And how to use .CSS??

Comment: How to use .CSS ?? In Jquery

Comment: I'm building an example. Will edit my answer in a sec.

Comment: Your code seems to be right with the `.css`. Mode code? Can you put a sample in jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @user3316092, did the jfiddle example helped? Does it work?

Comment: I changed tyour code from .nav-bar to .navbar as the class name but it dont works I dont know is the problem :/

Comment: Post some more code on your question or create a jsfiddle.